# refactor Express-Handlebars helper functions to separate files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I use Express-Handlebars and want to refactor this code example to separate files

```
    const express = require('express');
    const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

    const handlebars = exphbs.create({
        defaultLayout: 'index',
        extname: 'hbs',
        helpers: {
          foo: function () { // first helper
            return 'FOO!';
          },
          bar: function () { // second helper
            return 'BAR!';
          } 
          //, nth helper ...
        }
    });
```

The reason is why would you place all the HTML logic into your `app.js` file. I want to have 1 file for 1 helper.

How can I register the helpers from external files? Could someone provide me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create one module per helper for example inside `helpers` folder:

helpers/foo.js:

```
var foo = function () {
    return 'FOO!';
}

module.exports = foo;
```

helpers/bar.js:

```
var bar = function () {
    return 'BAR!';
}

module.exports = bar;
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const foo = require('helpers/foo');
const bar = require('helpers/bar');

const handlebars = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    extname: 'hbs',
    helpers: {
      foo: foo,
      bar: bar 
    }
});
```